# How to correctly translate UML Association, Aggregation and Composition to a Hibernate mapping?

Tags: uml, persistence, hibernate

There is a number of questions about the differences between UML Association, Aggregation and Composition out there and many many answers, some practical and some phylosofical. Here I'm asking we talk about practical differences!

In some answers I found:

1. Reference languages like Java can't really implement Compositions, since the instance life cycle is controlled by the garbage collection;
2. Associations and Aggregations have no practical difference, so we should just drop Aggregations and work with Associations and Compositions; still, those two kinds of relationship exist;
3. Those three concepts make sense only in programming languages like C++, that have an instance-based (and not reference-based) object model;
4. Aggregation allows many owners, Composition does not; a few sources advogate different.

However, no answer I've found so far approached those concepts in the context of persistent objects. No examples were given considering persistence, even though it is a very usual development condition.

When an object is persisted in a database system we do have a life cycle model free from garbage collection since an instance (or table row if you will) deletion happens in response to a deliberated act from some part of the software implementing some product requirement.

The difference between Association and Composition is indeed very clear, they will produce different annotations in code. A very noticiable difference is that with a Composition we will have cascade delete enabled, so when the Owner id deleted, the Items are also deleted. In Association there is no cascade delete enabled.

However, what differences will we find when annotating Association and Aggregation, specially, when in both cases we have a cardinality bigger than 1?

Comment: You are thinking about the wrong kind of practical here. The practical aspects of these differences don't lie in the specific language features used, but in how you think about the relationships of various objects/elements/components in your code, in how they are supposed to work together, and how that plays into the future changes & maintenance. So statements like "Java can't really implement Composition" make no sense - how long the orphaned instance lives before GC is irrelevant; what matters is how you treat the composed object (release the parent & the whole composite is unreachable).

Comment: Also, regarding association: both aggregation and composition are *specialized kinds of* association. Association is just a more generalized relationship used to indicate that an object is in some way related to some other object - e.g. it calls it, or depends on it somehow, or whatever. The associated objects don't even have to be persisted (e.g., they could exist only in a running application), and if they are, the fact that they are associated at runtime may or may not translate to a database relationship.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović: thanks for comments. I know Association is a superconcept of Aggregation and Composition. However, it is not an abstract concept, since it can be instantiated in a UML model. So, if all those three kinds of constructs can be instantiated in a UML model, it is reasonable to ask when they should be used. Again, Association and Composition have particularly clear motivations, but Aggregation still kept me in the dark until you gave your second comment. With Association one class does not cascade persists, but in Aggregation it does. You just answered my question!

Comment: @FilipMilovanović: please, post an answer and I will select it

Answer (score 3):

[Aggregations](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/aggregation.html?context=class-diagrams) and [compositions](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/composition.html?context=class-diagrams) are [specialized associations](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/association.html?context=class-diagrams) that carry some additional semantic (i.e. meaning):

- UML doesn't specify the semantic of aggregation ("*Precise semantics of shared aggregation varies by application area and modeler*", page 110), except that the aggregated objects may be subject to shared ownership. In practice, aggregation is frequently used for showing a part-whole relationship.
- UML specifies composition as an exclusive ownership with the control of the lifecycle. The composed objects do not survive their owner.

When persisting objects with an [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) such as [Hibernate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_(framework)),  the associations, aggregations and compositions can therefore be implemented in exactly the same way.  The most common practices are:

- [identity fields](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/identityField.html) are used as primary key to uniquely identify an object of a certain class;
- [foreign key mapping](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/foreignKeyMapping.html) is used to implement one-to-many associations;
- [association tables](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/associationTableMapping.html) are required to implement many-to-many associations.

The difference between composition and aggregation or simple associations lie in the behavior outside the table (i.e.  deleting composed objects when the composite is deleted).

For composition, [an older DBMS practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48385825/3723423) is to use a [compound key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_key): a first member of the compound key is a foreign key corresponding to the owning object,  and as a second member to have a sequential number that is unique but only for the corresponding foreign key.  Sounds complex but it's simple: imagine you have a `PurchaseOrder` table with a primary key a `POid`.  Each `PurchaseOrderLine` would then have an compound key, made of the `POid` and a line number.  I'm not an hibernate specialist,  but [here a blog post](https://coderanch.com/t/528754/databases/Hibernate-annotations-relationship-composite-primary) that explains how it works.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not a newbie in database or Hibernate. I understand primary keys and composite keys. My question, however, is about the mappging differences among all those kind of relationships.